# Dataframe - InvalidIndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using below code -

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv ("csv3.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv ("csv4.csv")
df2['cat'] = df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Complexity')['Themes'])
df2 = df2['cat'].value_counts().rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df2)
```

And error I am getting is

```
----> 4 df2['cat'] = df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Complexity')['Themes
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Please help me with if I am doing anything wrong, this works fine when Complexity and Themes is replaced by Value and Type respectively.

Comment: You have duplicates in  `df2.Complexity`. You cannot map with duplicate index (which value should be chosen to map?)

Comment: @QuangHoang -  If `df2['cat'] = df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Complexity')['Themes'])` this is replaced with `df2['cat'] = df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Value')['Type'])` it works well. Rest all in the dataframe is same its failing only when column names are changed

Comment: So? Your `Value` column does not have duplicates. I think you meant to set `Type` as index...

Comment: @QuangHoang both has duplicates, but i am wondering when its works with column name Value and Type, why not when its replaced with Complexity and Themes